# Animate children of ng-repeat using | AngularJS, ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

The only answer related I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123563/angularjs-animating-children-of-repeated-elements) but I found no comfort in the answer. I'm trying to animate the child of an ng-repeat group of elements but failing miserably, tried various combinations of ng-enter ng-enter-actives etc but cant seem to get my desired effect.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="ex in [1,2,3,4]" class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
 .inner{
        transition:1s linear all;
    }
    .outer.ng-enter .inner{
        width:1px;
    }
    .outer.ng-enter-active .inner{
        width:100px;
    }
    .outer.ng-active .inner{
        width:100px;
    }
```

I'm just trying to get the child of ng-repeat to animate on load. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0p3r495/3/) I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a directive:

```
myApp.directive('animm',function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            $timeout(function(){
                el.addClass('readyy');
            }, 100);
        }
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
.inner{
    transition:1s linear all;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
.outer.readyy .inner{
    width:100px;
}
```

Could even do some trickery with the scope id to offset them? See fiddle update

http://jsfiddle.net/j0p3r495/5/